# Azure Service fault logs in C# application

Tags: c#, azure, azure-servicebus-topics

I am using different azure service,(Kuberentes cluster,API,Key vault,IOT HUB, ,cosmos db,storage account,datalake,ad b2c,Power BI).I want the failure message and time of these service in my c# (other any other language)application. Is there any api for this purpose ?.or any way to get failure message and time ?

Failure means
failure state or non responding state of azure service.

I just want the any failure or fault message.Not normal message and service message.i didn't find any such kind filter or rest api or type

Comment: do you mean something like/different than health checks?

Comment: NO. I just want the log of service which is not responding or  service which is restarted  .sample cosmos db is failed due to internal issue of azure or restarted due to low memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact purpose of your question ,But if you want to check the service is available or not (failed due to some internal issue of azure) then use resource health check.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/resource-health-faq

Comment: this what i looking for

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using multiple Azure Services your best bet would be to integrate your application with Azure Application Insights. Application Insights is a monitoring and diagnostics tool provided by Azure. Configuring Application Insights is extremely easy. You can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/dotnetcore-quick-start).

Depending upon your framework and choice of language there are multiple options. Once you have installed the Application Insights SDK in your solution, it will automatically start monitoring and reporting all failures. All external dependencies in your application will get automatically tracked and all failures will be logged automatically (in 90% of the scenarios you won't have to write custom code to track these errors). Other parameters like time and failure messages will also get logged. In case you are interested to check which Azure Services are monitored check the [link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/monitor-reference).

Along with this you will also get the option to log custom messages, events, metrics, exceptions or dependencies.

Comment: Application insight is used to monitoring my environment not azure service right?

Comment: If you are looking for the logs in Azure Services then your best best in Azure Monitor, Check the 2nd link that I gave, that contains which services have Azure Monitor. You can create alerts on the Azure Monitor, to get notified of failures.

Comment: i don't have any centralised application .I have only one c# application to receive the logs form azure service

Comment: Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/monitor-reference

Comment: Btw, which service are you trying to monitor? And can you specific like what kind of errors?

Comment: i want to monitor all service mentioned in question.
but all theses are connected to different application

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor azure services then you must create a diagnostic setting for each azure service to send its logs to log analytics workspace to use with an azure monitor or for archiving you can use Azure storage archive tier/cool tier or Azure Event hubs to forward outside of Azure(like configuring with Kafka).

For more information visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/

Comment: i didn't find proper way to get message from azure monitor.I found one Monitor Rest api document,but still response are understandable format. I just want the any failure or fault message.i didn't find any such kind filter or rest api or type

Comment: do you mean something you need rest API to fetch data from the azure monitor?